# PDO - Join Queries and output correct data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm currently trying to make very basic support tickets.

I have two database tables `support` and  `supportreplies`
support has columns `id, userid, message, creationdate` and supportreplies has `id, supportid, userid, comment, messagedate`

Table layout:

```
1) support (id, userid, message, creationdate)
2) supportreplies (id, supportid, userid, comment, messagedate)
```

Then the join.

```
$sqlt=$dbht->prepare("SELECT *
FROM supportreplies 
LEFT JOIN support 
ON supportreplies.supportid=support.id
GROUP BY supportid ORDER BY supportid DESC");
```

Then outputting the tickets like this:

```
foreach ($sqlt->fetchAll() as $rows){
echo $rows['message']; 
echo $rows['creationdate'];
echo $rows['message'];
echo $rows['comment'];
echo $rows['messagedate'];
}
```

Now this is working to an extent, except that it only loads the first comment for each ticket. I'm lost at what to try next, how can I get this working?

Comment: We need to see the table layouts.

Comment: I'd say it's because of your grouping

Comment: what is supportid? exactly

Comment: supportid is the id of the original support request, it is support.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something that needs to be done in two different queries. One needs to `SELECT` all the tickets, and then for each ticket, run another query to get all the replies with a supportreplies.supportid that matches a support.id.

This can be done natively in MySQL using something called Subqueries: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

You will have to find the way to implement this for your code though ;)

Comment: Ended up just making it outside of PDO, standard Mysqli. Cheers for sending me in the direction of sub queries though, it's a good read.

Comment: Glad my answer was useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `GROUP BY` clause.  by grouping your records by supportid, you're effectively "grouping" all results for each supportid into one record.

Is there a reason that you need your results grouped?  If not, you could simply remove the clause:

```
$sqlt=$dbht->prepare("SELECT *
FROM supportreplies 
LEFT JOIN support 
ON supportreplies.supportid=support.id
ORDER BY supportid DESC")
```